# Keras model to fit polynomial

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, non-linear-regression

I generated some data from a 4th degree polynomial and wanted to create a regression model in Keras to fit this polynomial. The problem is that predictions after fitting seem to be basically linear. Since this is my first time working with neural nets I assume I made a very trivial and stupid mistake.

Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=200, input_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=45))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=50)

loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=100)

classes = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=1)
```

`x_train` and `y_train` are numpy arrays containing the first 9900 entries from [this file](https://www.file-upload.com/qd88va9uo6ta).

I tried different batch_sizes, number of epochs, layer sizes and amounts of training data. Nothing seems to help.

Please point out everything you see that does not make sense!

Comment: Could you provide x_train, y_train and x_test? So that the reader could run your code.

Comment: I added a link to the data file to the original question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neural networks generally won't do a good job in extrapolating polynomial functions. However, if your training and testing data are from the same range, you could achieve quite nice results. I generated some data and used your code:

```
import numpy as np
x_train=np.random.rand(9000)
y_train=x_train**4+x_train**3-x_train
x_train=x_train.reshape(len(x_train),1)

x_test=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y_test=x_test**4+x_test**3-x_test
x_test=x_test.reshape(len(x_test),1)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=200, input_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=45))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=50, verbose=1)

loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=100)

classes = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=1)

test=x_test.reshape(-1)
plt.plot(test,classes,c='r')
plt.plot(test,y_test,c='b')
plt.show()
```

Note that I increased `epochs` to 40 to get more iterations and more accurate results. I also set `verbose=1` to be able to see how the loss behaves. The loss is indeed decreasing down to `7.4564e-04`, and below is the result that I got. The red line is the prediction of the network, and the blue line is the correct value. You can see that they are quite close to each other.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For the polynomial that I chose the above code does not really work. But changing the activation form a ReLU to sigmoid(10*x) yields acceptable results. Maybe starting with fitting polynomials for a first shot at neural nets was a poor choice.

Comment: @FloodLuszt in a single layer in 1d Relus are performing piecewise linear regression.  You are perhaps better off just using one layer and perhaps increasing the number of nodes significantly.  Essentially how well you can fit a curve with line segments depends on the convexity of the function [ so the more the gradient changes, the more nodes you need to add].  see my answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/375658/27556